# Why is my hit test bringing back way too many items?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a hit test I'm using on a canvas with a bunch of lines loaded from a dxf file and it's returning an unexpectedly large amount of line objects each time even though my ellipse geometry is quite small. See below:

```
 private void map_page_canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedElements = new List<DependencyObject>();
            Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
            var rect = new EllipseGeometry(pt, 0.5, 0.5);

            var hitTestParams = new GeometryHitTestParameters(rect);

            var resultCallback = new HitTestResultCallback(
                result => HitTestResultBehavior.Continue);

            var filterCallback = new HitTestFilterCallback(
                element =>
                {
                    if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) == map_page_canvas)
                    {
                        selectedElements.Add(element);
                    }
                    return HitTestFilterBehavior.Continue;
                });

            VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(
                map_page_canvas, filterCallback, resultCallback, hitTestParams);

            foreach (var element in selectedElements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.GetType());
            }
        }
```

Here's the canvas setup:

```
  <Canvas Background="Transparent"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
        ClipToBounds="True"
        SizeChanged="ViewportSizeChanged"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="ViewportMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="ViewportMouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="ViewportMouseMove"
        MouseWheel="ViewportMouseWheel">
            <Canvas x:Name="map_page_canvas" Width="800" Height="500" ClipToBounds="False"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" MouseWheel="ViewportMouseWheel" MouseLeftButtonDown="map_page_canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        >
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX="1" CenterY="1" />
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <MatrixTransform x:Name="transform"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5 0.5 0 0.5" BorderBrush="Black" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: Not looked at your code but it will return everything within the area of your ellipse, not just the first.

Comment: And ... My first choice would be to use an approximation based on the X and y difference from click point to significant points in a list. Maybe your requirement changed though.

Comment: Why are you flipping your canvas with that layout transform? That's probably going to complicate things. I'd consider translating the points in code instead before adding anything to the canvas if source co-ordinates don't measure from top left.

Comment: Where I'm clicking on screen there should be at most one line yet I'm getting results for over 20.

Answer (score 2):

Adding elements must be done in the HitTestResultCallback, not in the HitTestFilterCallback. In fact, you should not use a HitTestFilterCallback at all.

```
var resultCallback = new HitTestResultCallback(
    result =>
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(result.VisualHit) == map_page_canvas)
        {
            hitList.Add(result.VisualHit);
        }
                
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    });

...

VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(map_page_canvas, null, resultCallback, hitTestParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, replacing my filterCallback variable with a method fixed my issue. See below method:

```
 private HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(result.VisualHit) == map_page_canvas)
            {
                hitList.Add(result.VisualHit);
            }  

            return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue; 
        }
```